# Erroneous blockchain transactions...more coins than I specified!

Tags: transactions, blockchain, altcoin

This isn't directly related to Bitcoin; rather this is related to Infinitecoin, however the technologies are virtually the same.

The other day I sent 2,000 IFC from my wallet (Infinitecoin-QT for Windows, version 1.8.8.0) to another address.

I looked at this transaction on the blockchain, and it is reporting that I sent 60,000 IFC.

The transaction shows the 2,000 IFC as being sent to the correct address, and then another 58,000 IFC to an unknown address.

Here is a link to the transaction for more info:

https://coinplorer.com/IFC/Transactions/106a8812b178c74b65303c42c8a754941db4a296b861eab116d71bd8f4c0492c

I'd really like to know where my 58,000 IFC went!

P.S. My wallet does not show 58,000 missing coins

Comment: Don't worry, altcoins are on-topic here. See the tour page for more details:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

The 58000 coins have gone to a change address in your wallet. When you sent 2000 from the 60000 UTXO you've had 60000 go out to two inputs: your change address and the spending address.

Keep this in mind: *when spending from a single input you're  sending the whole lot*!

Comment: What is a change address, and how do I verify this against my wallet?

Comment: Open your debug console from the QT client, and do 'validateaddress x' on the address. Ismine should be true.